# How to "see" the covariance matrix and mean vector?

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am working with following model specifications (Regression, Modelle, Methoden und Anwendungen, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg (2009), p. 147):

$$Y \sim MVN(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$$
$$\beta|\sigma^2 \sim MVN(m, \sigma^2M)$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim IG(a_0, b_0)$$

The author derives the full conditional density like:
[image]

The author finds that:

$$\Sigma_{\beta} = (\frac{1}{\sigma^2}X^TX + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}M^{-1})^{-1}$$
and $$\mu_{\beta} = \Sigma_{\beta}(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}X^Ty + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}M^{-1}m)$$

I worked my self through the mathematics of the full conditional but I lack the intuition to understand how the author (or one in general) can see what exactly $\Sigma_{\beta}$ as well as $\mu_{\beta}$ are here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking how to interpret $\Sigma$ and $\mu$?

Comment: Not interpret but I can not understand how the author determined what exactly is $\Sigma$ and $\mu$ is. Like I just see some matrices multiplied or added together. I hope this was understandable... xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always like to work backwards: if I knew the mean and variance, the expression would look like:

$$
(\beta - \mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(\beta-\mu)
$$

and expanding that out gives:

$$
(\beta - \mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(\beta-\mu) 
$$
$$
= \beta^\top\Sigma^{-1}\beta - 2\beta^\top\Sigma^{-1}\mu + \mu^\top\Sigma^{-1}\mu 
$$
$$
= \beta^\top\Sigma^{-1}\beta - 2\beta^\top\big[\Sigma^{-1}\mu\big] +C
$$

So if I have some expression like $\beta^\top\mathbf{A}\beta - 2\beta^\top\mathbf{b}$, I know that $\Sigma^{-1}=\mathbf{A}$ or that $\Sigma=\mathbf{A}^{-1}$.

Then, I know that $\Sigma^{-1}\mu = \mathbf{b}$, or that $\mu = \Sigma\mathbf{b}$.

Comment: So basically I just need to bring it in this form and I can read it - speaking for a MVN distribution. Thank you again. :)